# Staggered DiD: Single Treatment

Tags: econometrics, causality, difference-in-difference

Consider a study involving subjects from 30 cohorts. The key event is a law passed by the Federal Government in 2017, which banned the use of certain vaping products.

Among the 30 cohorts, individuals from 15 cohorts were assessed for the use of banned vaping products before the 2017 ban. Conversely, individuals from the remaining 15 cohorts were evaluated for the use of these products after 2017, but at different time points. Specifically, subjects from 5 cohorts were tested in 2018, another 5 cohorts in 2019, and the remaining cohorts in 2020.

Given that women from the 15 cohorts were tested at varying time periods post the 2017 ban, does this scenario qualify as a case of ***staggered treatment adoption***?

[image]

Comment: No, as I understand your post, everyone was treated at the exact same time. Staggered adoption would require, for example, that different states enacted the ban at different times so that people living in different states were treated at different times.

Comment: @num_39, Thank you, just to clarify.  Although the event (Federal Law implement) on Jan 1st 2017, and different cohorts were measured in different years post ban (2018, 2019, 2020) this is not a staggered adoption correct ?

Comment: A cohort could be “tested” later but still subjected to the treatment in 2017. Did states implement the ban in different years, or were the different cohorts just tested/assessed in different years? Please clarify, if possible.

Comment: @ThomasBilach, Hi Thomas, good question.  As now, all I know is that Federal Govt passed the law in 2017 , and different cohorts were tested during different years.

Comment: Correct, if the law was enacted on Jan 1, 2017 for everyone, then regardless of when cohorts were measured, you don't have staggered treatment adoption.

Comment: Operator please close this question. I have received good advice from num39 and Thomas Bilach. Thanks.